# Running python3 multiprocessing job with slurm makes lots of core.###### files. What are they?

Tags: python-3.x, python-multiprocessing, slurm

So I have a python3 job that is being run by slurm. The python job uses lots of multiprocessing, generating about 20 or so threads. The code is far from perfect, uses lots of memory, and occasionally reaches some unexpected data and throws an error. That in itself is not a problem, I don't need every one of the 20 process to complete.

The issue is that sometimes something is causing the program to create files named like core.356729, (the number after the dot changes), and these files are massive! Like GB of data. Eventually I end up with so many that I don't have any disk space left and all my jobs are stopped. I can't tell what they are, their contents are not human readable. Google searches for "core files slurm" or "core.number files" are not giving anything relevant.

The quick and dirty solution would be just to add a process that deletes these files as soon as they appear. But I'd rather understand why they are being created first.

Does anyone know what would create a file of the format "core.######"? Is there a name for this type of file? Is there any way to identify which slurm job created the file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those are core dump files used for debugging. They're essentially the contents of memory for the process that crashed. You can disable their creation with `ulimit -c 0`

Comment: Can I ask if they are specific to python3. slurm or multiprocessing?

Comment: They're at the level of the operating system (i.e. Linux). Have a look on this [ArchLinux page](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Core_dump) for more info.